# Need help in flex visualisation

Tags: apache-flex, visualization

I have an array of data which I need to display in a tree form. Birdeye seems to be a good tool but has poor documentation. Can you suggest some good flex visualisation tools? Or some birdeye tutorials to get the hang of it? (Google wasn't very helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: http://lab.kapit.fr/display/visualizer/Visualizer ? I only took a superficial look at them a while back and they seemed pretty slick.

Otherwise, if it's just a tree, you might be able to write your own easily. Convert your array to a two-dimensional layout model and place the nodes yourself based on simple height/width arithmetic. BirdEye graphs are quite a bit more complicated if you're looking for things like radial layout. [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) might be able to help you in that case, but you'll have to run it on the server and interpret the results on the flex client.